# How to export a matrix with indices in Octave?

Tags: octave, file-management

Suppose I have a matrix

```
a = [1, 2, 3; 11, 12, 13; 21, 22, 23]
```

How to save it to a txt or csv file in the following manner?

Row, Column, Value

```
1 1 1
1 2 2
1 3 3
2 1 11
2 2 12
2 3 13
3 1 21
3 2 22
3 3 23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `dlmwrite` command, using space (i.e. `' '`) as a delimiter, e.g.:

```
octave:1> a = [1, 2, 3; 11, 12, 13; 21, 22, 23]
a =
    1    2    3
   11   12   13
   21   22   23

octave:2> [Cols, Rows] = ndgrid( 1 : size(a, 2),   1: size(a, 1) );
octave:3> M = [ Rows(:), Cols(:), a'(:) ];
octave:4> dlmwrite('out.ssv', M, ' ');
```

<sub>PS. Presumably you have a typo in your a matrix and meant to write `a = [1, 2, 3;   11, 12, 13;   21, 22, 23]`</sub>

Comment: It says the *'ngrid' function belongs to the control package from Octave Forge
which seems to not be installed in your system.* I am using Octave 4.2.2 in Ubuntu 18.04. Is the function ngrid available in later versions of Octave?

Comment: I installed the package control from Octave Forge. Now it says *warning: the 'ngrid' function belongs to the control package from Octave Forge
but has not yet been implemented.* So, is this feature availabe in later versions of Octave? Which version of Octave are you using?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi `ndgrid`. Not `ngrid`. `ndgrid` is a standard function in base octave. The `nd` stands for "N-Dimensional".

Answer (score 1):

Columns 1 and 2 will always have the same pattern, and column three is just a stacked column of the rows, so the following should work.  I broke it out step by step, but I'm sure it could be tightened up into fewer lines:

```
>> a = [1, 2, 3; 11, 12, 13; 21, 22, 23];

>> [r, c] = size(a);
r =  3
c =  3

>> col1 = repelem([1:r]',c)
col1 =

   1
   1
   1
   2
   2
   2
   3
   3
   3

>> col2 = repmat([1:c]',r,1)
col2 = 
   1
   2
   3
   1
   2
   3
   1
   2
   3

>> col3 = a'(:)
col3 =

    1
    2
    3
   11
   12
   13
   21
   22
   23

>> output = [col1, col2, col3]
output = 
    1    1    1
    1    2    2
    1    3    3
    2    1   11
    2    2   12
    2    3   13
    3    1   21
    3    2   22
    3    3   23
```

then there are a couple options for how to save it. the simplest is probably:

```
>> dlmwrite ('filename.csv', output)
```